# Python Error with scraping Forum for Title and URL

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape the title and the URL of each Posting at the Forum of the URL, so that when a new Post is created with 1 of the Titles below i'd like to receive a Mail with that Link of the Post.

Please do not be so harsh with me i'm a beginner with Python and Scraping

I have multiple Problems.

1: at the While(True) Function the "soup" is red underlined with the Error: Undefined variable 'soup'
2: When commenting out the While(True) Function then the Program will not run. I get no error.
3: When there is a new Posting with one of my Criterias, how do I get the URL of that Post?

**Titles**

```
def Jeti_DC_16
def Jeti_DC_16_v2
def Jeti_DS_16
def Jeti_DS16_v2
```

**My FullCode**

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import smtplib
import time
import lxml
import pprint
import json


URL = 'https://www.rc-network.de/forums/biete-rc-elektronik-zubeh%C3%B6r.135/'


def scrape_page_metadata(URL):
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36'}

    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    response = get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    metadata = {
        'Jeti_DC_16': Jeti_DC_16(soup, URL),
        'jeti_dc_16_2': Jeti_DC_16_v2(soup, URL),
        'jeti_ds_16': Jeti_DS_16(soup, URL),
        'jeti_ds_16_2': Jeti_DS_16_v2(soup, URL)
    }
    pp.pprint(metadata)
    return metadata


def Jeti_DC_16(soup, URL):

    jeti_dc_16 = None
    if soup.name.string:
        jeti_dc_16 = soup.title.string
    elif soup.find_all("div", class_='structItem-title'):
        jeti_dc_16 = soup.find_all(
            "div", class_='structItem-title').get('text')
    else:
        jeti_dc_16 = URL.split('//')[1]
        return jeti_dc_16.split('/')[0].rsplit('.')[1].capitalize()
    return jeti_dc_16


def Jeti_DC_16_v2(soup, URL):

    jeti_dc_16_v2 = None
    if soup.name.string:
        jeti_dc_16_v2 = soup.title.string
    elif soup.find_all("div", class_='structItem-title'):
        jeti_dc_16_v2 = soup.find_all(
            "div", class_='structItem-title').get('text')
    else:
        jeti_dc_16_v2 = URL.split('//')[1]
        return jeti_dc_16_v2.split('/')[0].rsplit('.')[1].capitalize()
    return jeti_dc_16_v2


def Jeti_DS_16(soup, URL):

    jeti_ds_16 = None
    if soup.jeti_ds_16.string:
        jeti_ds_16 = soup.jeti_ds_16.string
    elif soup.find_all("div", class_='structItem-title'):
        jeti_ds_16 = soup.find_all(
            "div", class_='structItem-title').get('text')
    else:
        jeti_ds_16 = URL.split('//')[1]
        return jeti_ds_16.split('/')[0].rsplit('.')[1].capitalize()
    return jeti_ds_16


def Jeti_DS_16_v2(soup, URL):

    jeti_ds_16_v2 = None
    if soup.name.string:
        jeti_ds_16_v2 = soup.title.string
    elif soup.find_all("div", class_='structItem-title'):
        jeti_ds_16_v2 = soup.find_all(
            "div", class_='structItem-title').get('text')
    else:
        jeti_dc_16_v2 = URL.split('//')[1]
        return jeti_dc_16_v2.split('/')[0].rsplit('.')[1].capitalize()
    return jeti_ds_16_v2

    # search_for_class = soup.find_all(
    #     'div', class_='structItem-title')
    # Jeti_DS_16 = soup.find_all(text="Jeti DS 16")
    # Jeti_DS_16_v2 = soup.find_all(text="Jeti DS 16 2")
    # Jeti_DC_16 = soup.find_all(text="Jeti DC 16")
    # Jeti_DC_16_v2 = soup.find_all(text="Jeti DC 16 2")


if(Jeti_DC_16, Jeti_DC_16_v2, Jeti_DS_16, Jeti_DS_16_v2):
    send_mail()

    # # print('Die Nummer {0} {1} {2} {3} wurden gezogen'.format(
    # #     Jeti_DC_16, Jeti_DC_16_v2, Jeti_DS_16, Jeti_DS_16_v2))
    # for i in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'structItem-title'}):
    #     print(i.a['href'])

    # first_result = search_for_class[2]
    # print(first_result.text)
    # print(Jeti_DC_16, Jeti_DC_16_v2, Jeti_DS_16, Jeti_DS_16_v2)

    def send_mail():
        with open('/Users/blackbox/Desktop/SynologyDrive/Programmieren/rc-network/credentials.json', 'r') as myFile:
            data = myFile.read()

        obj = json.loads(data)
        print("test: " + str(obj['passwd']))

        server_ssl = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        server_ssl.ehlo()
        # server.starttls()
        # server.ehlo()

        server_ssl.login('secure@gmail.com', 'secure')

        subject = 'Es gibt ein neuer Post im RC-Network auf deine gespeicherte Anfragen. Sieh in dir an{Link to Post}'
        body = 'Sieh es dir an Link: https://www.rc-network.de/forums/biete-rc-elektronik-zubeh%C3%B6r.135/'

        msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"
        emails = ["secure@gmx.de"]

        server_ssl.sendmail(
            'secure@gmail.com',
            emails,
            msg
        )
        print('e-Mail wurde versendet!')

    #     server_ssl.quit


while(True):
    Jeti_DC_16(soup, URL)
    Jeti_DC_16_v2(soup, URL)
    Jeti_DS_16(soup, URL)
    Jeti_DS_16_v2(soup, URL)
    time.sleep(10)
    # time.sleep(86400)
```

Comment: where do you create `soup` ? I don't see it - and it seems your IDE/editor also don't see where you create `soup` so it use red underlined.

Comment: you create `soup` inside function `scrape_page_metadata` - but this is local variable `soup` and it doesn't exists outside this function `scrape_page_metadata`. You should use `return soup` to get it outside function. Other problem - you create `scrape_page_metadata` but you never run it. Why? You should use `scrape_page_metadata` instead of `while True` or inside `while True`

Comment: you check `if(Jeti_DC_16, Jeti_DC_16_v2, Jeti_DS_16, Jeti_DS_16_v2):` but `Jeti_DC_16, Jeti_DC_16_v2, Jeti_DS_16, Jeti_DS_16_v2` are functions names and names will always give `True` . You should check `metadata["Jeti_DC_16"]`, etc.

Comment: all your functions `Jeti_DC_16, Jeti_DC_16_v2, Jeti_DS_16, Jeti_DS_16_v2` look the same and probably they return the same element. You can use one of them and delete others. Or you should change them and they should search different elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create `soup` inside `scrape_page_metadata` and it is local varible which doesn't exist outside `scrape_page_metadata`. In `while`-loop you should rather use `scrape_page_metadata()` instead of functions `Jeti_DC_16(), Jeti_DC_16_v2(), Jeti_DS_16(), Jeti_DS_16_v2()`

And this functions gives you `metadata` which you should check instead of `if(Jeti_DC_16, Jeti_DC_16_v2, Jeti_DS_16, Jeti_DS_16_v2)`

More or less (you have to use correct value in place of `...` because I don't know what you want to compare)

```
while True:
    metadata = scrape_page_metadata(URL)

    if metadata["Jeti_DC_16"] == ... and metadata["Jeti_DC_16_v2"] == ... and metadata["Jeti_DS_16"] == ... and metadata["Jeti_DS_16_v2"] == ...:
        send_mail()
    
    time.sleep(10)
```

But there are other problems

All your functions `Jeti_DC_16, Jeti_DC_16_v2, Jeti_DS_16, Jeti_DS_16_v2` look the same and probably they return the same element. You could use one of them and delete others. Or you should change them and they should search different elements.

Probably you would have to use more `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed because I think this code needs a lot changes yet.

For example `find_all()` gives list with results and you can't use `get()` which needs single element. You need `for`-loop to get all titles from all elements

More or less

```
jeti_ds_16_v2 = soup.find_all("div", class_='structItem-itle')
jeti_ds_16_v2 = [item.get('text') for item in jeti_ds_16_v2]
```

Comment: What I wanted with all of these functions ```Jeti_DC_16, Jeti_DC_16_v2, Jeti_DS_16, Jeti_DS_16_v2``` so that I get at the End for each entry it own URL so when the Mail is send I get the Name that Link for the Post so i only. If i understood your answer right, I only need to create 1 Function and inside there i can search for all of the Strings and get the Like?

Comment: all you functions use the same code - with the same `find_all("div", class_='structItem-title'):` - so they will find the same element on page - if you want to search different elements then you should have different code in functions. Different names for variables don't change code.